# Flexbox css , how to stack content on top of each other

Tags: html, css, frontend

```css
html,body { height:100%; }

#continaer-flex{
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 100px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.product{
    width:25%;
}
#flex-title{
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
#left-content{
    width: 17%;
    flex: 4;

}
#right-sorting{
    width: 83%;
    justify-content: center;
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 100%;
}
.navbar-brand{
    padding-left: 50px;
}
<style scoped>
#border{
    border-style: solid none none none;
    border-color: gray;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 4px;
}
#category{
    font-size: 20px;
}
#arrow{
    font-size: 16px;
}
#price{
    color: green;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.card{
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="app">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="app">
            <div class="row justify-content-center" id="continaer-flex">
                <div id="right-sorting">
                    <div v-for="product in products" class="col-md-3 col-sm-12" >
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" @click="goToProductPage(product['id'],product['product_name'])">
                            <img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/829/733/png-clipart-logo-brand-product-trademark-font-not-found-logo-brand.png" class="card-img-top" alt="product img">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">{{ product['product_name'] }}</h4>
                                <p class="card-text">{{ product['product_description'] }}</p>
                                <p id="price">${{ product['product_price'] }}</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">Take me there</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div v-for="product in products" class="col-md-3 col-sm-12" >
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" @click="goToProductPage(product['id'],product['product_name'])">
                            <img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/829/733/png-clipart-logo-brand-product-trademark-font-not-found-logo-brand.png" class="card-img-top" alt="product img">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">{{ product['product_name'] }}</h4>
                                <p class="card-text">{{ product['product_description'] }}</p>
                                <p id="price">${{ product['product_price'] }}</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">Take me there</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="left-content">
                    <h3 @click="changeCat">Category  <fa id="arrow" :icon="cat_pressed ? 'chevron-down' : 'chevron-right'" /></h3>
                    <div id="category" >
                        <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
                        <label for="vehicle1">All the categories will show up here
                        </label><br>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

i made a flexbox using css and the issue is when there is no space in the screen they are not stacking on top of each other, insted they stack behind each other

here is my css:

```
 #continaer-flex{
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 100px;
}
#right-sorting{
    width: 83%;
    justify-content: center;
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 100%;
}
```

when there is not enough space the flexbox doesn't extend from the bottom instead they go behind each other,
im using vue and thats why there is v-for etc..

Comment: I think you want to use the flex-wrap property https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap

Comment: didn't work the issue is the flexbox doesn't extends from the bottom and do it like bootstrap columns

Comment: I think it's better to add the full code with snippet so it can be clear and easy to get

Comment: i added the snippet i hope u can help

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, but reading the answer you made (to arieljoud) solution is to use px instead of %:

**Solution:**

```
#continaer-flex{
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
#right-sorting{
   width: 820px;
  justify-content: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: if you need any help for this issue, ask me with more information